# A question about AsyncSpinner

Tags: ros, asyncspinner

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Dear all,

I would like to know what would happen with`ros::AsyncSpinner spinner(0);`

Does that mean the callback is still in the same thread as the main program?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/201807/a-question-about-asyncspinner/) by [ZiyangLI](https://answers.ros.org/users/3542/ziyangli/) on ROS Answers with karma: 93 on 2015-01-27

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

According to the [ros::AsyncSpinner Class Reference](http://docs.ros.org/indigo/api/roscpp/html/classros_1_1AsyncSpinner.html#aa5b9b685b7eebebf18ed42697e209897) (from the `roscpp` [API docs](http://docs.ros.org/indigo/api/roscpp/html/index.html)):

> `ros::AsyncSpinner::AsyncSpinner(uint32_t thread_count)`
>
> Simple constructor. Uses the global callback queue.
>
> Parameters:
>
> thread_count: The number of threads to use. **A value of 0 means to use the number of processor cores**

---

Edit:

> Then the question becomes, what would happens if I use 1?

From the source of `AsyncSpinnerImpl::start()` (lines [143-167](http://docs.ros.org/indigo/api/roscpp/html/spinner_8cpp_source.html#l00143)):

```
void AsyncSpinnerImpl::start()
{
  [..]

  for (uint32_t i = 0; i < thread_count_; ++i)
  {
    threads_.create_thread(boost::bind(&AsyncSpinnerImpl::threadFunc, this));
  }
}
```

In this, `thread_count_` is set in the ctor of `AsyncSpinnerImpl` to be either equal to the nr of cpus, or to the value passed in via the ctor of `AsyncSpinner`.

> Does that mean the callback is still in the same thread as the main program? will the callback blocks the main loop?

If you specify a `thread_count` of 1, a single *additional* thread is created. So no, iiuc, the callback processing should not happen in the 'main loop'.

PS: I would've found it rather odd for a class called `AsyncSpinner` to return to synchronous behaviour only be changing the nr of threads it uses.

PPS: this is also partly explained in [roscpp/Overview/Callbacks and Spinning - Multi-threaded Spinning](http://wiki.ros.org/roscpp/Overview/Callbacks%20and%20Spinning#Multi-threaded_Spinning) on the ROS wiki.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2015-01-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ZiyangLI](https://answers.ros.org/users/3542/ziyangli/) on 2015-01-27**:
Thank you! Then the question becomes, what would happens if I use 1? Does that mean the callback is still in the same thread as the main program? will the callback blocks the main loop?